# Apple watch notification - tapping on the notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

On Apple Watch, the user can dismiss the notification or act on it by tapping an available action button (if any) or by launching your app.

if we click on any button, it raises the method (on the main view controller):

```
- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification
```

Question 1)
If I click on the notification (not on the buttons) which method is called? The app is not opened.

Question2)
Imagine that I have notification A and B.   If I tap on A , it raises the view Controller VA.B raises VBA. Is it possible to do this just tapping on the notification, without adding any button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into 1, too. Can you double check your app's settings inside the Apple Watch app on your iPhone/iPod/iPad, and make sure that Show App on Apple Watch is on? I never played with this setting but for some reason it got turned off.